# DNS cache issue or apache vhosts confusion?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain

I'm trying to move from one ubuntu VPS set up to another and I'm having subdomain issues, that I did not have on my old server. I am unsure whether my problem lies in the DNS records or with Apache.
Unfortunately I do not have access to the DNS records of my old server, only those of the new

**The problem:**

**domainname.com** and **www.domainname.com**
are not displaying code from my new server, the code on the old server is displaying
I want these URLs to show the code in `/var/www/domainname.com.live`

**stage.domainname.com**
is working as desired, showing code from my new server, specifically `/var/www/stage.domainname.com.live`

**Sanity check:**

- I have no .htaccess files
- I have checked that mod_rewrite is enabled
- The sites below are "enabled" with `a2ensite`
- The nameservers were switched to my new server 5 days ago

**DNS records for my new server:**

```
*.domainname.com        181.102.220.244 domainname.com  86400       A   
domainname.com        181.102.220.244 domainname.com  600         A 
stage.domainname.com    181.102.220.244 domainname.com  600         A
```

**Code excerpts from my new server:**

file /etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname.com.live
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ServerSignature Email

    <Directory "/var/www/domainname.com.live">
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|admin\.php|index\.php|assets|assets-uploaded|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?$1 [L]
        RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|admin\.php|index\.php|assets|assets-uploaded|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

file /etc/apache2/sites-available/stage.domainname.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  stage.domainname.com
    ServerAlias stage.domainname.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/stage.domainname.com.live
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ServerSignature Email

    <Directory "/var/www/stage.domainname.com.live">
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|admin\.php|index\.php|assets|assets-uploaded|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?$1 [L]
        RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|admin\.php|index\.php|assets|assets-uploaded|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

**nslookup**

```
    $nslookup domainname.com

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   domain.com
    Address: oldServerIP

    $nslookup stage.domainname.com

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name:   stage.domainname.com
    Address: newServerIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just set this up and did you have the stage domain on the old server? What does a nslookup say for all domains? Do all records point to the correct server?

Seems to me more like a DNS-cache issue than an apache one.

Comment: I've added nslookup info above. I switched nameservers about 5 days ago. I've been folling around trying to get the subdomains configured for days.